# How to bind "readonly" in custom element in Aurelia?

Tags: binding, aurelia, readonly, custom-element

I have the following element in html file:

```
<require from="_controls/time-slot-slider"></require>

    <time-slot-slider id="zeitraum" min="0" max="24" length="4" value="4"
                              value.two-way="functionConfig.startTime" if.bind="functionConfig.isAutomatic === true"
                              readonly.bind="!mayFunctionTestEditTime"></time-slot-slider>
```

Custom element is here(time-slot-slider.html):

```
<template class="range-slider time-slot">
  <div>${duration}</div>
  <input type="range" min.bind="min" max.bind="maxStart" step.bind="step" value.bind="value">
</template>
```

and time-slot-slider.ts :

```
import { bindable, customElement } from 'aurelia-templating'
import moment from 'moment/moment'
import Moment = moment.Moment

@customElement('time-slot-slider')
export class TimeSlotSlider {

  @bindable public min: number = 0.0
  @bindable public max: number = 24.0
  @bindable public step: number = 0.5
  @bindable public value: number = 0.0
  @bindable public length: number = 4.0

  public get maxStart (): number {
    return this.max - this.length
  }

  public get from (): Moment {
    return TimeSlotSlider.numberToMoment(this.value)
  }
....
```

But **readonly.bind** doesn't work. I tried to bind readonly by

`@bindable readOnly: boolean` but I didn't have any success. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you only apply `readonly` to your custom element:

```
<time-slot-slider readonly.bind="!mayFunctionTestEditTime"></time-slot-slider>
```

You've mentioned that you'd tried defining `@bindable readOnly: boolean` on the component's viewmodel, but I assume you had forgotten to apply it to the `input` itself. Obviously, just the presence of it won't magically cause it to be applied the the input, therefore like that, you basically have a property on your viewmodel that you don't use for anything.

The solution is to keep that `@bindable readonly: boolean` property on the VM but also bind its value to the actual input - essentially "forwarding" the value the component gets down to the actual control:

```
<input type="range" readonly.bind="readonly" ... />
```

It is also a good idea to give the properties a default value, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46343800/4205470) answer (especially the comments) for details as to why.

Comment: I did it. But I get this warning: cannot find 'readonly' in type 'TimeSlotSlider'

Comment: You wrote `readOnly` instead of `readonly`. Note the uppercase `O`. Change `readOnly` to `readonly` in your viewmodel OR `readonly.bind` to `read-only.bind` in the HTML where you use that component.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much